# Javascript/jQuery: search within object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

```
<div class="days">
  <input name="days-select" type="radio" value="Mon" > Mon </input>
  <br>
  <input name="days-select" type="radio" value="Tue" > Tue </input>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    radiobtn = $('.days');
    radiobtn.find('value="Tue"').prop('checked', 'checked');
  });
</script>
```

Basically, I need a two-stage search. First, find the group of radio buttons, then set one of them as checked. HOWEVER, I do not want to combine these two steps into one. Thanks for the hint.

BTW, since I am new to Javascript I would like to ask how to debug this code. For example, single-step through the script, and after "radiobtn = $('.days');" check whether "radiobtn" is assigned correctly etc. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI: `radiobtn.find('[value="Tue"]')`.  The `[]` tells it to search attributes.

Comment: To debug your code, you could use the developer tools built into the Chrome browser.

Comment: What's your question?  I'm a little confused with what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: There is no `</input>` tag.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I tried '[]', doesn't work.

Comment: [Debug in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging): Press F12, open the Sources tab, Open the navigator (the small arrow or Ctrl+O). You can now click on any line-number in an open file to place a breakpoint.

Comment: Why not just use `$('.days input[value="Tue"]').prop('checked',true)`?

Comment: @j08691, since I already have the handle of "radiobtn", why bother adding it again? That's exactly what I want to know: how to search within an object?

Comment: I'm asking why the two-step? Why not just knock it out in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="days">
    <input id="dayMonday" name="days-select" type="radio" value="Mon">
    <label for="dayMonday">Monday</label>
    <br>
    <input id="dayTuesday" name="days-select" type="radio" value="Tue">
    <label for="dayTuesday">Tuesday</label>
</div>
```

**script**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      //your .days selector is actually getting the div and not the radio button
      var div = $('.days');
      //maybe here you want to do some things with the div...
      //...
      var radiobtn = div.find('input[value="Tue"]');
      //maybe here you want to do some things with the radio button...
      //...

      //now you have the correct element...
      radiobtn.prop('checked', true);

      //F12 in Chrome to see the console
      console.log(radiobtn);
      //notice the selector property returns: .days input[value="Tue"]
      console.log(radiobtn.selector);
      //so you could just do this all in one line:
      $('.days input[value="Tue"]').prop('checked', true);

      //see last commented line regarding this next line...
      //$('.days input[value="Tue"]').click(
      //     function(){ console.log("you clicked Tuesday");});
      //Note: you could do this: 
      //radiobtn.click();
      //... or this:
      //$('.days input[value="Tue"]').click();
      //but it also fires the click event which is why you would see 
      //"you clicked Tuesday" in the console with the above line uncommented
      });
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwENJ/1).